# Issues building react native app for android

Tags: react-native

I are trying to build a react native app but I am experiencing some issues.

```
> Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease
R8: Missing class: rx.Observable$OnSubscribe
R8: Missing class: rx.functions.Action0

Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Daemon is stopping immediately JVM garbage collector thrashing and after running out of JVM memory
```

It seem the issue has to do with `enableProguardInReleaseBuilds` in the `build.gradle`. Is there a way to build the app with the `enableProguardInReleaseBuilds` set to `true`.

I understand that this will help reduce the size of the output APK.

Comment: was anyone able to solve this please.. i have similar problem but have no idea how to solve it